# Powershell: Using a variable for the fields in Select-Object

Tags: powershell

I'm building a script that is creating `csv` files. Each `csv` has a different set of fields. Everything is working great, but I want to control the column order output.  I have a variable that contains the fields and the order I want them in.

I know that I can use Select-Object to control this.  What I want to do is this:

```
$Fields = "ID,Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4"
$Obj | Select-Object $Fields | Export-CSV -Path $OutputPath
```

Instead of this:

```
$Obj | Select-Object "ID","Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4" | Export-CSV -Path $OutputPath
```

Since I have several different formats and want to just pass the field list as a parameter to the function doing the work.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is absolutely possible.

When you pass in `"ID,"Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"` that is just an array of strings.

To show a literal example:

```
$Fields = "ID","Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"
$Obj |Select-object $Fields |export-csv -path $OutputPath
```

How you assign the value of `$Fields` during each iteration is up to you.