# Use Variable for Select-Object or Format-Table

Tags: powershell

I have a a similar question like this: [Question 44460843](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460843/powershell-using-a-variable-for-the-fields-in-select-object)

I want to use variables for the fields.

This example works well:

```
$x = ("Id,ProcessName,CPU").split(",")
Get-Process | ft -a $x
```

But how do i get it, if i want custom fields like this?

```
Get-Process | ft -a Id,ProcessName,@{Name = 'CPUx' ; Expression = {$_.CPU}}
```

I tried this, but it don't works:

```
$x = ("Id,ProcessName,@{Name = 'CPUx' ; Expression = {$_.CPU}}").split(",")
Get-Process | ft -a $x
```

Does anybody know how to do this?
I am a lazy guy and want to avoid this copy/paste orgies with long text.

Comment: that looks like the `splatting` idea. take a look at `Get-Help about_Splatting` for how that works. [*grin*]

Comment: `$x = 'Id','ProcessName',@{Name = 'CPUx' ; Expression = {$_.CPU}}; Get-Process | ft -a $x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- The answer applies analogously to the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet, which is what should be used to extract properties for later *programmatic processing*.
  `Format-*` cmdlets, such as [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) in this case (whose built-in alias is `ft`), are only intended to produce *for-display* formatting; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.

[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) has provided the solution in a comment:

```sh
$x = 'Id', 'ProcessName', @{ Name = 'CPUx' ; Expression = { $_.CPU } }
Get-Process | Format-Table -AutoSize $x  # same as: ft -a $x
```

That is, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44460884/45375) to the linked question applies in your case as well, even though it happens to use only *literal strings* as property names:

*Directly* construct an array of property names and [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), using `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), which allows you to use any mix of literals and variables; e.g.:

```sh
$pName = 'processName'                               # property name
$pCpu = @{ Name = 'CPUx' ; Expression = { $_.CPU } } # calculated property

$x = 'Id', $pName, $pCpu
```

Do *not* start with a *single string* that you split into an array of tokens with `.Split()`, because it will limit you to property *names*, given that the tokens are invariably *strings*.

---

As an aside:

The array binds *positionally* to [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)'s (`ft`'s) `-Property` parameter, and you can easily discover that as well as the fact that an *array* of property names / calculated properties is discovered as follows:

```
PS> Format-Table -?
...

SYNTAX
    Format-Table [[-Property] <System.Object[]>] ...

DESCRIPTION
...
```

- The outer `[...]` tells you that the parameter is optional as a whole.
- The `[...]` around `-Property` tells you that specifying the parameter name explicitly is optional, i.e. that *positional* binding is supported.
- `<System.Object[]>` tells you that an array (`[]`) of `System.Object` instances is expected as the type of the argument(s).

To get more information about what objects, specifically, may be passed, inspect the parameter individually:

```
PS> Get-Help Format-Table -Parameter Property

-Property <System.Object[]>
    Specifies the object properties that appear in the display and the order 
    in which they appear. Type one or more property names, separated 
    by commas, or use a hash table to display a calculated property. 
    Wildcards are permitted.
...
```